# Hive - How to display 0 for partitions that are empty?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

There is 1 partition for date in my table. For that partition, there are 2 folders in hdfs, e.g. 01-01-2018 and 02-01-2018. In 02-01-2018 there is no data at all.

So when I query like below:

`select date, count(*) from table1 group by date`

It will only return the output for partition with data like below:

`01-01-2018      168`

I need the output to be like below:

`01-01-2018      168
 02-01-2018      0`

How to achieve that output? Thank you.

Comment: use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from a table with all the dates to `table``

Comment: when you run this command what is the output you get: `select date frome table1  where date='02-01-2018'` ?

Comment: If you have another table (object) with date list you can do it, else you can't